# VBA: Copy Entire Row Deleting All Text to the right of the first comma and insert it in the next Row

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to create a Macro which will help me look for "," and if it finds it. It will copy the entire row without the first "," it sees and insert another row underneath.

[image]

For example. 9877352, 9877354

It will turn that one line into two lines with the same information.

Only different is 9877352 will be on one row and then 9877354 will be in the following row in the same table.

Code So Far:

```
Sub comma()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim text As String
    Dim myCell As Range

    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To FinalRow
        thisvalue = Cells(i, 5).Value

        If thisvalue Like "*,*" Then
            Cells(i, 5).EntireRow.Copy

            'I don't know what to put here

            'Cells(i, 5).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(i, 5).TextToColumns` will distribute the Order Numbers column wise. You could then use `transpose` to distribute them to row i + 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a chance of there being more than two commas in a cell, I would use an array. Does the column ever change? If not I would do something like this...

```
Sub comma()

Dim Order As Variant, cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("E:E") 'Enter static column reference here
    If cell.Value Like "*,*" Then
        Order = Split(cell, ",")
        For i = LBound(Order) To UBound(Order)
            If i = 0 Then
            cell.Value = Order(i)
        Else
            cell.EntireRow.Copy
            cell.EntireRow.Insert
            Range("E" & cell.Row) = Trim(Order(i))
        End If
        Next i
    Else
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,  There are chances that there will be more then one comma.

I tried copying and pasting the code it comes up with user defined type not defined referencing

    dim order() as variable, cell as range

Comment: I just edited the code. Sorry about that! It should have said Variant instead of variable. Also added a few extra lines for completeness.

Comment: This has fixed the problem